# Import Maven dependencies from other password protected Repositories

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for coding in Java.

How can i use external Maven package repositories that are password protected?

For Maven, i have a settings.xml file, which contains the credentials to the repositories/servers. Those work with the command line `mvn -s my/settings.xml clean compile` command and also in IntelliJ IDEA.

Putting the `settings.xml` in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` as suggested by @khmarbaise would be enough for most users, but i am using the Docker Dev Extension, which doesn't work with that approach.

How do i get it to work with Visual Studio Code and the Docker Dev Extension?

Comment: I recommend to put the settings.xml in your home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` which is the default location ....

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise thanks for the suggestion. However, i think this doesn't quite work with the Docker Dev Container extension. Could you think of any other way?

Comment: So you are building inside a container also locally?